# Dynamic inline styling LWC based on JS getter

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on a component where I put an inline styling in a div tag dynamically based on a getter in the associated JS file.

Here is the code of the html file:

```
<template>
   <lightning-card title="Canvas subscriber">
       <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
           <div class="templateBodyClass" style={colorStyle} ></div>
       </lightning-layout-item>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here is the code of the JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import {registerListener, unRegisterAllListeners} from 'c/pubsub';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class CanvasSubscriber extends LightningElement {

    @wire (CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
    color;

    connectedCallback(){
        // Specify the event to listen to and the method to trigger when event occurs
        registerListener('changedColor', this.handleChangedColor, this);
    }

    disconnectedCallback(){
        unRegisterAllListeners(this);
    }

    handleChangedColor(colorCodeFromEvent) {
        console.log('Received color ==> '+colorCodeFromEvent);
        this.color = colorCodeFromEvent;
    }

    get colorStyle(){
        return `background-color:${this.color}`;
    }

}
```

The html code doesn't compile when I try to push the changes to the default scratch org.
The error messages I get:

- "} expected"
- "at-rule or selector expected"
- "Do not use empty rulesets"

What is going wrong? It is the code of tutorial 200 on Udemy's course "Salesforce Certified Platform Developer I (LWC & AURA also)". I saw that the example code, provided with the course, gives the same issue.

Comment: code looks good to me assuming you have a color property defined in the js class, did you get any compilation error?

Comment: Is the shared html file complete ? Do you have two template blocks without any attribute in your html file ? In that case , html compilation can fail. Rest works fine , just tried it.

Comment: Answering to Anmol Kumar's point: I did define a color property in the js class. I just put the entire js class content here-above. The html file name in VSCode is colored red, indicating that there is an issue. When I hoover over the style attribute the error message says "Do not use empty rulesetscss(emptyRules)">.

Comment: Regarding Rohit's comment: what you see here-above is the complete content of the html file. So, there are no template blocks without any attribute.

Comment: Is there perhaps a VS Code setting to change so that this error doesn't get considered as a blocking error? I mean blocking for compilation.

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464170/visual-studio-code-css-error-do-not-use-empty-rulesets